# Two way lookup from key value pair

Tags: c++, key

I have a set of settings in a class that I need to iterate through:

A,B,C,D

The end result of each iteration is a single number, what is the best way to find out from the index of the result list what the values of A,B,C and D are?

e.g.

```
A= 2 to 10 in steps of 0.1
B= 4 to 20 in steps of 0.5
C= 5 to 50 in steps of 0.2
D= 6 to 70 in steps of 3
```

And the results come as indexes in a list from each iteration e.g.

```
Iteration[0] = 2; (A=2,B=4,C=5,D=6)
Iteration[1] = 10; (A=2,B=4,C=5,D=9)
```

If I have the original settings what is the best way to reverse lookup the values of A,B,C,D from the index number?

I also need to carry out the opposite calculation too, from a set of settings, what is the index.

Any help would be great!

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at boost reverse mapping
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html
Maybe this helps